# divide char array into N equal parts matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, split, char

I have a char array, for example:

```
a = '123456abced5421f'
```

and I want to divide it into equal parts (e.g: `b(1) = '123456ab'` and `b(2) = 'ced5421f'`) so when I call `b(1)` it will return 8 elements not just 1 element.

How can I do this in Matlab?

I tried using cell array and reshape, the cell array will increase the size of the array so I don't want to use it, and the reshape will return only 1 element.

Comment: You can use a length. `b = a(1,8)`. [Here you can find more Information about `array-indexing`](https://de.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reshape` to turn your string into a character matrix, i.e. with some number of rows and 8 columns:

```
a = '123456abced5421f';
b = reshape(a,8,[]).'
>> b = 
     ['123456ab'
      'ced5421f']
```

Then access each row (8 character string) using standard row indexing

```
b(1,:) % Row 1, all columns
>> ans = '123456ab'
```

---

If you really wanted to just be able to access each row using a single index, you must use cell arrays. To convert `b` to the desired cell array we can use `mat2cell`.

```
c = mat2cell(b, [1 1], 8);
```

Then indexing is easy

```
c{1}
>> ans = '123456ab'
```

---

All together without defining `b`, and making it generic:

```
% number of elements in a must be divisible by 8
c = mat2cell(reshape(a,8,[]).', ones(1, numel(a)/8), 8);
```

Comment: I don't want to use cell arrays because they increase the size of my array and I want the size to be the same

Comment: Use row indexing as shown in this answer then, or a helper function to shortcut your indexing as shown by EBH

Comment: thank you it worked ... my problem is that I have a text and I want to divide it into blocks each of size 16 bytes then encrypt each block , but I don't know what to use the char type will double the size of bits ,I'm really confused

Comment: no problem with this method , but I have another problem with the input I want the encryption algorithm to process each 16 byte at a time , but I don't know if I should use the char type as the input to the algorithm or the uint8 as the input ,using char will require 8 elements and using uint8 will require 16 elements ... any advice ?

Comment: Sounds like you want to be asking a new question,  with a nice clear example to go with any existing code and the problem you have

Comment: yeah I will ask :) .. one last question can I call b(1) into another function based on your method ?

Comment: Yes, you can use it like `myfunction(b(1,:))` or `myfunction(c{1})`... or you use my method in combination with a helper function as shown by EBH if for some reason you can't stand using a colon, but that might make things more difficult later on.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the arrary, whithout using a cell-array, use a helper function:

```
a = '123456abced5421f';
b = @(n) a((n-1)*8+1:(n*8));
```

Now you can type:

```
>> b(1)
ans =
    '123456ab'
>> b(2)
ans =
    'ced5421f'
```

And if you want less or more than 8 elements, just set this as a variable:

```
m = 16; % or any other integer number
b = @(n) a((n-1)*m+1:(n*m));
```

The advantage of this method is that **it consumes no memory** (the helper function is negligible), as you don't create any new variable.

---

If you want to be able to access several elements in `b` in one call, than it's better to use a temporary array for that (with row indexing as suggested in [@Wolfies answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45274461/2627163)):

```
m = 8;
tmp = reshape(a,m,[]).';
b = @(n) tmp(n,:);
```

Then you can type:

```
>> b(1:2)
ans =
  2×8 char array
    '123456ab'
    'ced5421f'
```

Comment: Not sure if it's worth mentioning, depending on the OP's (or future visitors') experience, that assignment operations like `b(1) = 'abcdefgh'` are not valid, and this method is essentially "read only". Nice thinking though.

Comment: From the OP it seems that it's not an assignment `=` but just a way to show what in `b()`

Comment: Yep, I agree, as I say just leaving a note for future visitors who may find this method useful :)

Comment: can I use your way to divide my array into blocks and then take each block and process it 
I want each block to be encrypted then decrypted using an algorithm

Comment: If you only want to access `a` in chunks of 8 elements, you can use the first option above. If you want to work on all the parts together, use the second option. **Either way, you will get a better answer if you'll explain your goal in more details.

Comment: I implement the method you listed above it's working but now I want each chunk (block) to be encrypted using rc6 the problem is how the input should be (char or uint8) I'm confused with this problem for almost 2 weeks now , rc6 take each block and divide it in to 4 parts then work with each part

Comment: I'm not sure what you are confused about, but you can use these methods with any function that accepts char as input, the output of `b(1)` is of type char in both of them. If you have a question about your `rc6` function then you should ask a different question about that.